# Python Flask sqlalchemy - sum columns by date

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the table

```
class NutritionConsumed(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'nutritionconsumed'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False )
    calories = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    totalfat = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
```

and I want to sum up the 'calories' and 'total fat' columns by 'date'

so im trying

```
@app.route('/nutritiontotals')
def nutritiontotals():
    nutritiontotals = NutritionConsumed.query.filter_by(func.sum(NutritionConsumed.calories), 
                                                        func.sum(NutritionConsumed.totalfat),
                                                        ).group_by(NutritionConsumed.date).all()
    return render_template('nutritiontotals.html', nutritiontotals=nutritiontotals)
```

but I get the error

```
TypeError: filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you are including func.sum in the filter part of the query. It sounds like you are looking to return that as a value as opposed to filtering by it.

If so, instead of the ModelClass.query syntax that flask_sqlalchemy provides, I would recommend structuring your query using the db.session.query(query_args).filter(filter_args) syntax that SQLAlchemy uses in their documentation. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#querying

Using the db.session.query() syntax, you can include multiple classes or columns in the query section (assuming you have the appropriate joins).

Haven't tested it out, but this should work.

```
 q = db.session.query(NutritionConsumed.date, 
                      func.sum(NutritionConsumed.calories),               
                      func.sum(NutritionConsumed.totalfat))\
               .group_by(NutritionConsumed.date).all()
```

Comment: but then I would need to use 'engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test2.db', echo=True)'
so I could have 'Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)'. but I'm in flask so I don't have that I have 'app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db''
follow by 'app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret' ' then 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)'

Comment: no need to change your configuration.  When using flask_sqlalchemy, you access the session via db.session.  so instead of session.query() as with the basic sqlalchemy orm docs, you use db.session.query()